# Remove/normalize accents in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, normalization

I'm trying to remove accents from a string in portuguese and I've found solutions like the one presented in [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-diacritics-in-strings) but it seems a bit 'ugly'. Isn't any library in JS/Jquery that can make this work for you? In Java you have for instance the class Normalizer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Comment: Can't you just save that solution in a file and use as library?

Comment: copy paste..  not difficult. The tedious thing would be to look for the characters you need, make it compatible with different formats, browsers, quick... etc etc... There you have some functions that people argue are working... and you did not find a solution by itself... then This one is your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this library https://github.com/dundalek/latinize

I've not fully explored the code, but it seems to work